# How to switch between two stores just to create links

Tags: magento-enterprise, frontend

I need to to include links to categories/CMS pages in another store in my navigation menu. So it would look something like this:

```
             <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('home'); ?>" <?php if ($currentUrl == Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('home') || $currentUrl == Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)) { ?>class="active" <?php } ?>>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('our-products'); ?>" <?php if ($currentUrl == Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('our-products')) { ?>class="active" <?php } ?>>Our Products</a></li>
    <?php
    switch_to_another_store($store_id_2); ?>
     <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('home'); ?>" <?php if ($currentUrl == Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('home') || $currentUrl == Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)) { ?>class="active" <?php } ?>>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('our-products'); ?>" <?php if ($currentUrl == Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl('our-products')) { ?>class="active" <?php } ?>>Our Products</a></li>
<?php 
switch_to_another_store($store_id_1); ?>
```

Don't know if this will work or not, but some help would be awesome

I found a  [Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10152/how-to-create-a-link-to-a-product-in-a-different-website-store-view)

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation([the other store ID]);

$product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([product ID]);
echo '<a href="'.$product->getProductUrl().'">Shop now!</a>';

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `?__store=<storecode>` to the links.